# How to convert a Next 13.4.4 Js Project into a PWA?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm currently working on a Next Js 13 project and I need to convert it into PWA.

I've been trying to follow the next-pwa documentation but it's hard to apply it on a Next 13 project because of the structure.
The project is working perfectly but I just need to convert it into PWA.

This is my project structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2wwJ.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Update next.config.js

> ```
> /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
>
> const withPWA = require("next-pwa")({
>   dest: "public",
>   register: true,
>   skipWaiting: true,
>   disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
> });
>
> module.exports = withPWA({
>   reactStrictMode: true,
> });
> ```

2. Add in layout.tsx

> ```
>       <head>
>           <link
>               rel="manifest"
>               href="/manifest.json"
>           />
>       </head>
> ```

3. Add manifest.json with images in public folder (Use [manifest generator](https://www.simicart.com/manifest-generator.html/)) (Don't forget to select standalone option)
4. > npm run build
5. > npm start
6. Open chrome

Comment: Don't forget npm i next-pwa

Comment: I'm very grateful Harsh Shah! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Also with the new metadata approach you might have to configure the manifest there

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";
```

As such

```
    export const metadata: Metadata = {
      title: "PWA hype",
      viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0",
      manifest: "/clients/tvvest/manifest.json",
      themeColor: "#ffffff",
      ...
    };
```

in ie `layout.tsx` to have it appear in `<head>`